# Is it possible for an appropriately vaporized crystal to have vapor properties in any way related to it's crystal?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, crystal-structure

Is it possible for an appropriately vaporized$^{1}$ crystal to have vapor properties in any way$^{2}$ related to it's crystal, or unique to the fact it was a crystal in it's previous phase?

The motivation for this question is regarding any potential applications as an analysis method.

$^{1}$ As a non-chemist its difficult to define this properly. Essentially meaning under appropriately controlled lab conditions.

$^{2}$ Stochastically or otherwise.

Comment: Depends how loosely you define vapor. You could probably spall nanocrystals off a bulk solid at relatively low energies and keep them airborne, though if the fragments are too small, they will no longer resemble the bulk crystal.

Comment: interesting thanks @NicolauSakerNeto would such airborne fragments constitute as a phase change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a homogeneous substance entirely into a vapour does not provide a simple way of obtaining information about the thermodynamic stability of the condensed phase from which it originated, since gas phases typically (almost by definition) do not store such information.

However, the equilibrium vapor pressure of a condensed substance reflects the chemical potential of the condensed phase. At equilibrium the chemical potential of the two phases should be equal. This principle can be exploited to investigate the thermodynamic properties of a substance in isolation or as part of a mixture. So if it is possible to establish equilibrium conditions between condensed and vapor phases and to avoid formation of competing crystal forms, then the answer would be yes, this property (the vapor pressure) is related to the crystal form.

In addition, some techniques probe phase transitions to learn about materials, for instance temperature scanning [calorimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_scanning_calorimetry) techniques. These might also monitor the rate of mass loss from the condensed phase. The rate of conversion into the gas (or other) phase can inform on the structure of the condensed phase.

Comment: See also (e.g.) https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/18/3419/2018/ and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010188923713

Comment: many thanks for the description and references, it is exactly from the analytic perspective i was thinking. unsure why downvoted, a broad question yes. but as your references show, a legitimate one.

Comment: @antimony I'm happy the answer was useful. Your question is a bit vague about the objective, but it brings up interesting ideas. You might want to clarify why this is of interest to you (the objective).